# Storing values to the configuration

Tags: cakephp

I have a custom Config file in cake php and I added the following settings, how can I modify them from say the app_controller or a view?. I was reading on Configure::Store() but havent found the proper way to do it... what would be the correct sintax to achieve this?

Thank you

```
<?php
$config['versioning'] = array(
        'version' => '',
        'year' => ''
    );
```

Comment: do you mean "writing to the file"? like saving different configs to it permanently?

Comment: yes thats exactly what i meant

Answer (score 0):

you mean Configure::write() and Configure::read() I assume:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/925/Configure-Methods

Comment: maybe this helps: http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Configure-store-in-the-same-file-used-by-Configure-load-td1289230.html